# How to initialize AuDaLib40?

Tags: c#

I am trying to instantiate AuDaLib40.Library but the error appears:
[image]

The config file is like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Maybe you need to add something else?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide all code and errors as text, not as pictures of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. I figured it out myself. A common mistake in the documentation and error. You just had to replace the Image section with Images and everything worked.